# Should I be passing S_ variables into functions - PHP

Tags: php, class, global

I am building a little website as a project on the side and am having a go at mvc.

I have built a request class, and a router class.

Simple enough question, but I have read all over the place that globals are bad for such whatever reason, so should I be passing in, $_GET, $_POST, $_SERVER etc into my request class, or just referencing them from inside the request class.

```
new Request($_GET, $_POST, $_SERVER);
```

or

```
new Request();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main aspects of OOP is abstraction.
So the class should not know about your Global Variables.
What if you change the key of your GET.
The first Method is the most common way.